# codeigniter encryption / decryption function returns empty string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to login using codeigniter, but not able to do so. 
Then i tried to copy password from DB and pass it to dycription->decode() function, and it's returning empty string.

Here is the code

```
var_dump($this->encryption->decode('s0xxxxxxXjrUxxxxxxBTxxxxhc'));
```

output was: **string(0) ""**

And this code also returning empty strings

```
$decoded_password = $this->encryption->decode($encoded_password); 
$decoded_username = $this->encryption->decode($encoded_username);
```

What i am doing wrong here?

UPDATE: i tried encrypting a string and PRINT IT then decrypt and PRINT, After encryption it returns NULL/Empty and after decryption it returns NULL/Empty (Obvious). 
Code is below

```
$encval = $this->encryption->encode('codeigniter');
echo $encval.'  --  IT WAS --'.'codeigniter';
echo "<br>---------------------------------------------------<br>";
echo $this->encryption->decode($encval);
```

OUTPUT: ^Nothing

Comment: I would not use codeigniter encryption for password use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: That is okay, but i have got an already built system that is using CI encryption.

Comment: @NomanAli wolfgang1983 is correct, you should not store your passwords in such a way that they can be decrypted. The function he suggests is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, there are 2 ways to use encryption in CI and both should not be used for password(use hashing). First find out which one was used to encrypt the password and then stored in DB.Also, its possible some kind of KEY may have been used while encrypting the password check this too.

Below are the 2 encryption libs available in CI.

1.Encrypt class : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encrypt.html

2.Encryption Lib: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

Comment: Following, Please Check `$password = $this->input->post('password'); // that's what the user enters on the registration form
  $encrypted_password = $this->encryption->encode($password); // our encrypted password `

Comment: So **Encryption** is used.

Comment: Try, $plain_text = 'This is a plain-text message!';
$ciphertext = $this->encryption->encrypt($plain_text);

// Outputs: This is a plain-text message!
echo $this->encryption->decrypt($ciphertext);

Comment: I've got this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Encryption::encrypt() `

Comment: have you include encryption library in your controller?

Comment: add this to you function/class construct :

 $this->load->library('encryption');

Comment: Also, what is the CI version? 
if this also doesnt work, probably its your DB tables character encoding issue. Please check your codeigniter charset in config

$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

versus the charset of your database. Your conflict is probably coming from there.

Answer (score 2):

I had come across this problem, too.. My problem arised from database column varchar lenght limitation.. So, cipher text stored with missing part.. I changed column lenght from 50 to 250 then default option decode and encode work correctly

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue by using Encryption library of Codeigniter, currently used library in my application was a little modified so it broke. now

```
$this->encryption->decrypt($cipher-text);
$this->encryption->encrypt($plain-text);
```

This is working perfectly. I had to replace all encodes / decodes with encrypt / decrypt.

Thanks for your time guyz

Answer (score 0):

Note*: **You might require to load the driver if no driver is loaded**

```
$this->encryption->initialize(
  array(
    'driver' => 'openssl',
    'cipher' => 'aes-256',
    'mode' => 'ctr',
    'key' => '123456' // OR any hash if empty then takes from config file
  )
);
```

// Switch to the MCrypt driver

```
$this->encryption->initialize(array('driver' => 'mcrypt'));
```

// Switch back to the OpenSSL driver

```
$this->encryption->initialize(array('driver' => 'openssl'));
```

reference: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html